# При запросе к Oracle метод ADO Execute возвращает пустой рекордсет

Tags: sql, oracle, 1с, ado.net

Есть огромный монструозный запрос с использованием множества таблиц и процедур. Запрос работает и получает данные в pl/sql developer. При использовании того же запроса метод execute возвращает пустой рекордсет. Другие запросы выполняются нормально.
Таймаут команды и соединения - 300. Попробовал создать вьюху с этим запросом - эффекта нет.

---

В чём может быть проблема? ADO не может использовать хранимые процедуры?

---

Работаю из среды 1С, не хотел устраивать камингаут. 
Но, на случай если это может помочь

```
ТекстЗапроса = "select * from V_STOCK_ALT t";

Соединение = Новый COMОбъект ("ADODB.Connection");
Соединение.ConnectionString = "---";
Соединение.ConnectionTimeout = 300;
Соединение.CommandTimeout = 300;
Соединение.Open();
РС = Соединение.Execute(ТекстЗапроса);
```

Вот собственно весь код который может представлять интерес.
РС.EOF имеет значение Истина.

---

Интересно то что поля в рекордсете заполнены, но нет данных, и то что запрос выполняется моментально, хотя должен секунд 90.

Comment: Полагаю, что без кода выполнения запроса и самого запроса ответить на вопрос будет сложно. Попробуйте выполнять запрос по частям и найти часть, которая вызывает проблемы. Также стоит приложить код, через который происходит обращение к БД.

Comment: В запросе 430 строк, уверен он не поможет.

Comment: Найти проблему в запросе без запроса сложно, если вообще возможно. Повторюсь, попробуйте разбить на части, либо вызывать процедуры/функции по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: @defaultlocale в общем все решилось. проблема и правда была в запросе. спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 1):

А разве Execute предназначен для получения набора данных? Мне что-то кажется, что он для INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE и всяких разных DDL... попробуйте что-то типа

```
НаборДанных = Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.RecordSet");
НаборДанных.Open(ТекстЗапроса, Соединение);
```

Comment: Я делал согласно этому [Execute Method (ADO Command)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection), вроде позволяет то что мне нужно. Но я конечно же попробовал то что вы предложили, к сожалению, не помогло. Так же получает поля, но не данные. Заодно попробовал ADODB.Command, та же история.

Answer (score 0):

Без текста запроса и правда было не разобраться, но 400 строк я выложить не мог.
Проблема заключалась в аргументах функции to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY').
В pl/sql developer функция работает с такими аргументами, при вызове из ado - нет, но запрос выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: Видимо есть разница в настройках локализации, из-за которых sysdate по-разному преобразовывается в строку. Вызов функции выглядит странно, `sysdate` уже возвращает дату и оборачивать его в `to_date` не нужно. Попробуйте использовать `sysdate` напрямую, если нужно округлить дату используйте [`trunc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2127.htm#OLADM706)